# How can we interact with 2 MonadError constraints having 2 different error types?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Say I have a function

```
function1 :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => m Int

function2 :: (MonadError Int m, MonadIO m) => m Int
```

and a function to transform `Int` into a `String`

```
renderException :: Int -> String
```

Is there a way to implement function3, which is reusing all 3 functions?

```
function3 :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => m Int
-- add the results from function1, function2 and 
-- transform function2 error into a String
```

Comment: This is a good use case for `ether` package. Check the tutorial here: https://int-index.github.io/ether/

Comment: Thanks I just discovered it today and is on my reading list :-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not sure this solves my issue. I can indeed use `ether` to have different constraints, `MonadExcept' e1` and `MonadExcept' e2` but I still can't remove one constraint and by providing a function `e1 -> e2` and have the resulting constraint being `MonadExcept e2`.

Comment: More reading leads me to think that what I want to do is actually not possible, `MonadError e` is a trap and once in a type signature, the `e` has to bubble up to the top. So the answer seems to be: "use `ExceptT` if you want to transform errors".

Comment: Oh dear I have so many questions on that topic... Would that be possible to use lenses for the error type? `function1 :: (MonadError e m, MonadIO m, Has String e) -> m Int`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I can use [`runExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExceptT):

```
-- runExceptT :: ExceptT e m a -> m (Either e a)
function3 :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => m Int
function3 =
  do ei <- runExceptT function1
     a  <- either (throwError . show) pure ei
     b  <- function2
     return (a + b)
```

So there's a way out of the `MonadError e` "trap". On the other hand I don't know how to encapsulate this `runExcept / either throwError` pattern.

Comment: In Haskell you can do everything. But it doesn't mean that you should. For example, it's a bad practice to combine `ExceptT` and `IO`. If I want to use `MonadError` with several exceptions I would create one ADT with constructor for each kind of exception. Pattern with `Has` is not really useful for `MonadError` because you don't want to extract part of exception usually, you want to extract part of some complex configuration. That's why lenses are usually used with `Reader` or `State`.

Comment: Maybe I need to explain why I want to do things this way. I want to use mtl for not having to pass a fix stack of effects throughout my application and I want to have "low-level" application declaring some errors which can then be interpreted as high-level error. For example you get a `NetworkError` which gets transformed to a `CatalogError` because that was the context in which the network call was made.

Comment: Creating an ADT for exceptions has the drawback that it is not modular. I need to come with all the exceptions for my whole application at once.

Comment: Actually I think this is what I'm after: https://github.com/gwils/next-level-mtl-with-classy-optics/blob/master/Slides.pdf. Thanks by the way for your help, I am indeed a Haskell beginner and trying to navigate the eco-system :-)

Comment: Yes, using Prisms is what you want for composable exceptions) You still create one data type which holds all exceptions but types of functions are polymorphic and composable. I wouldn't call yourself a Haskell beginner if you can understand what is written in these slides :)

Comment: I have been reading Haskell for a long time now, I just decided to start writing some a bit more seriously :-)

Comment: Amazing! I really like to see more people involved in Haskell :) If you have any advice in libraries or technologies or something like that, you can always contact me and ask any questions. Will glad to help in this Haskell journey! :)